# Como executar um trigger depois de outro trigger

Tags: jquery

Como fazer com que o segundo trigger somente seja executado depois do primeiro trigger carregar o html completamente?

```
$('#element-one').trigger('click');
// aguardar o primeiro ecento (carrega um html via ajax)

$('#element-two').trigger('change'); // só deveria ser executado depois do primeiro evento
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes utilizar o **[`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/)** para apontar para o primeiro clique e depois então acionar o segundo click utilizando o `trigger()`:

```
$("#target").click(function() {
    $( "#segundoElemento" ).trigger("click");
});
```

> Por acaso tive a ver e até existe um exemplo disso na [documentação do `trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#entry-examples)

Comment: O problema é que preciso que o primeiro seja um trigger. São umas sequencias de eventos acionados por triggers.